# For which values does the Gamma function yield an integer result?

Tags: gamma-function

Gamma Function:

$$\Gamma(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{t-1}e^{-x}dx$$

Is it known for which values of $t$ (real or complex), the value of $\Gamma(t)$ is integer?

Are there any known specific patterns of $t$, for which the value of $\Gamma(t)$ is integer?

Comment: Don't think so. Even only on the positive real half line, there are many but they have no characterization that I would be aware of.

Comment: Hard to say. Since $\Gamma(x)=(x-1)!$ and it is continuous, it visits all integers exactly once, and between integer values of $x$.(you can get arbitrarily more integer values for the function at non-integral points between $x$ and $x+1$ by taking large enough $x$).

Comment: $\Gamma(x)$ visits all integers except zero infinitely many times if we consider that $x$ may be a negative number.

Comment: Thank you @Did. I wasn't actually hoping to get an answer that would cover **all** integers. But are there certain patterns of $t$ for which $\Gamma(t)$ yields an integer result?

Comment: Thanks @Brad. Are there certain patterns of $t$ for which $\Gamma(t)$ yields an integer result?

Comment: Then I guess your question has to be made much more precise before some interesting answer arises.

Comment: Thank you @Did. Question revised.